# Android Text View and setTextIsSelectable

Tags: android, textview

I am working on a simple 15 puzzle game. I am having `TextView` for each block and all the 15 blocks are added dynamically. I want to touch and move the `TextView` around the layout. I am having a `RelativeLayout`. I am done with moving the block but sometimes the text inside the block is selected. I tried `t.setTextIsSelectable(false);` but at that time, the touch listener is not working. Is there a workaround for this problem. Below shown are pieces of code from the application.

```
/* Create the text view */
        TextView t = new TextView(this);

        /* Configure the text view */
        t.setLayoutParams(params);
        t.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wood);
        t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 42);
        t.setText(Integer.toString(j * R_BLOCKS + i + 1));
        t.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

        /* Add to layout */
        l.addView(t);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why not Buttons?

Since you're using your own drawables for skinning. You cannot make out the difference b/w a `TextView` and `Button`.

`Button`s are meant for clicking and `TextView`s for holding text, so life may be easier with `Button`s.